# Homogenity of Variances - F-test and Levene Test yield different results - which one to trust?

Tags: f-test, levenes-test

I want to perform a t-test on two independent samples with each n = 50. to check the assumptions, I ran an F-test for homogenity, which is significant. then I used SPSS which does a levene test by default and this levene test was not significant. I don't have the data here, but n = 50 (data are rental prices) is probably normal distributed. which test should I trust and why?
thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: If you can't be reasonably confident *a priori* that they're pretty close to the same, you should not assume they are the same (unless your sample sizes are equal, in which case it will do little harm). Basing your inference on the outcome of a previous test tends to be worse than not assuming equality of variance in the first place.

Comment: "probably normal distributed" - plot them?

Comment: In which country rental prices are approximately normally distributed?

Comment: I just did a KS-Test and they are normal distributed.